# Usage of spending time

Tags: word-usage, letter-writing

Which one is correct?

a)Thank you for the time you spent on reading this letter.

b)Thank you for taking the time on reading this letter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either of these:

> Thank you for the time you spent reading this letter.
>
> Thank you for taking the time to read this letter.

The preposition *on* isn't needed.

Answer (score -1):

How about just, "Thank you," Amir? Of course, if you were writing a letter to a customer who was seriously in arrears, you might say, "Thank you for acting on this matter before midnight tonight." But if you're just being thankful for the time it took them to the bottom of your letter, a simple, "Thank you" will do it.

Comment: I'd certainly appreciate a rationale for the downgrade.